# Kable (kableExtra) vertical scrollbar in knitted RMarkdown html_document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

The vertical scrollbar generated with `kableExtra` works in RStudio but doesn't work in the knitted html_document.

#### Example

Take the following `Rmd` file

````
---
  output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
iris %>% 
  kable %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
```
````

When running the chunk in RStudio, I see a vertical scrollbar

[image]

But after knitting, the vertical scrollbar is gone and the whole data.frame is printed

[image]

How can I get the vertical scrollbar to display in the knitted HTML the same as it was in RStudio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the function `scroll_box()` from the package `kableExtra`.

````
```{r}
iris %>% 
  kable %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>% 
 scroll_box(width = "500px", height = "200px")
```
````

To specify the size of the box, see the arguments in the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/kableExtra/man/scroll_box.html)